# Probability for choosing

Tags: probability

Hi I saw a probability question saying that a class of 100 people and want to chose 40 of them for some event. What is the probability that both Alice and Jack will be chosen for this event.

Should I use binomial for this question?

Comment: If both Alice and Jack are in the team, in how many ways, can you choose rest $38$ people in the team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability is $$\frac{\binom{98}{38}}{\binom{100}{40}}=\frac{98!\times40!\times 60!}{38!\times60!\times100!}=\frac{40\times39}{100\times99}=\frac{2\times 13}{5\times33}=\frac{26}{165}\approx0.15757575757$$

Answer (score 1):

You should use the hypergeometric distribution, The pmf is

$$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{K}{k} \binom{N - K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

You have two groups: $K=2$  (Alice and Jack) and the other people $N-K=100-2=98$. You choose $n=40$ people.

Alice and Jack belong to the first group ($k=2$). And the other chosen people belong to the second group ($n-k=38$).
Can you proceed?